# Connect to hidden service

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services, java

Without using tor2web is there a way for my Java program to connect to a hidden service .onion and retrieve data, for example search and then download a file?

I want the easiest solution possible, so it does not just have to be a programming solution.

Comment: Can you please describe what you mean by Java program? Any details of the current setup would help answer your question. I have a few suggestions but they involve Python, PHP, or Privoxy.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Silvertunnel-NG](http://sourceforge.net/projects/silvertunnel-ng/) and configure other libraries to use its socks proxy to connect to .onion .

Answer (score 0):

You can use any networking library for Java that speaks SOCKS5, then you can make connections via localhost:9050 to any location-hidden services (or clearnet services) via Tor.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a linux machine (possibly also other OSes), you can try the `torify` tool which comes with tor.  It receives a command line as an argument and sends the TCP connections of that program through the Tor process running on your machine.

PS: I use it myself to connect to a sshd running on my .onion from outside.